# ImageButton is not responding while moving in  android

Tags: android, animation, imagebutton

i'm moving a imageButton using translate animation.Image button contains a balloon image and it need to be burst when the image button is pressed. But the imageButton is not responding to click while moving. Any Soln?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the onclick reference is correct as **ImageButton.OnClickListener**:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new **ImageButton.OnClickListener**(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html

> Another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. **For instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to handle this.** With the property animation system, these constraints are completely removed, and you can animate any property of any object, including View objects, and the object itself is actually modified.

As it explains, you either need to take into account with your own logic where the button actually is or change to property animation, but this is only available for Honeycomb.